# What analytical methods are used to quantify C, O, N, and H in a sample?

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

A very common analytical method for detection of more than 70 elements is ICP-OES ([Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICP-OES)). But apparently, it's not suited for some substances (cited from [this paper](http://www.wfu.edu/chemistry/courses/jonesbt/334/icpreprint.pdf), section 6.2, page 12):

> The elements that are
>   not usually determined by ICP/OES fall into three basic
>   categories. The ﬁrst category includes those elements
>   that occur either as trace contaminants in the argon gas
>   used in the ICP/OES ($C$ from $CO_2$), constituents of the
>   sample solvent ($C$, $O$, $H$), or as contaminants from the
>   environment or atmosphere ($N$ for example). The second
>   category encompasses those elements that require high
>   excitation energy, such as the halogens. These elements
>   could be determined with poor LOD, however. The third
>   category is the family of short-lived radioactive elements
>   that are commonly determined by $\gamma$-ray spectrometry.

So, apparently, when I'm working with, say carbon-based fuels, and I want to determine $C$ contents, ICP-OES would not be the method of choice, at least not the standard variety. So, what else would be the typical choice? Or are there modifications to ICP-OES, such as using very pure $Ar$, or $He$, as the plasma gas and sealing the plasma chamber from the atmosphere?

Answer (score 3):

For N:

Total N = N from NO2 + N from NO3 + Total Kjeldahl N

The methods from [here](http://www.standardmethods.org/) are:

Liquid Chromatography: NO2, NO3

Specific electrodes: NO3, Kjeldahl

Spectrophotometry: NO2

This for water including wastewater. I don't know the aplicability for other samples.

Also ICP-MS is worth [researching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductively_coupled_plasma_mass_spectrometry).

Answer (score 1):

The analytical method preferred for CHNO (and also S, X, etc) determination is [elemental analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elemental_analysis), usually by combustion.

For example, if a molecule has the generic formula $\ce{C_wH_xN_yO_z}$, combustion would produce:

$$\ce{C_wH_xN_yO_z + (w +\frac{x}{4}+\frac{y}{4}+\frac{z}{2})O2 -> wCO2 + \frac{x}{2}H2O +\frac{y}{2}N2}$$

Determining the masses of $\ce{CO2}$, $\ce{H2O}$, and $\ce{N2}$ given off by the combustion is the first step in determining how much carbon, hydrogen, and nitrogen was in the original sample. The remaining mass is oxygen.